# How to increment a var in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I need some help. I have the last version of Selenium IDE and i cant increment a var with this method. The var is "MyVar" and its stored like this:

```
store 1 MyVar
```

And here you have the code what im using to increment the var

```
store javascript{storedVars.MyVar++;}
```

Do you know some other method to increment it?